# Fix / Replace ABS module

Tags: brakes, abs

I have an Audi A6, 2000.  My ABS light is on, and the brake light blinks.  I was told that the ABS module needed to be replaced at the cost of $850 minimum.

Is there a way to get these things fixed rather than having to fork out so much cash?  I can get the part cheaper if I do it myself, but the ABS module needs to be recoded to my car, so I have to take it to Audi anyway.

Also, is it just best practice to get a new part, rather than fix something like an ABS module?

UPDATE: Well I got my ABS part back and it works perfectly. So perhaps the way to go is to repair if you can. It's way cheaper, and appears to work great.

Comment: I have been investigating a bit more, and found a website that will fix my ABS sensor for only $110. They say most ABS modules they deal with can be repaired.
Anyone ever used this site? 
http://cheap-abs.com

Comment: it looks like you may have answered your own question.  That site indicates there are models that it can and cannot repair - I am assuming yours is repairable?

Comment: Yes, mine is one of the repairable models.  I've sent it in and will see what happens.

Answer (score 6):

The ABS light can be triggered by metallic debris or dirt on the wheel sensor(s). The sensor tries to read the position of the nearby reluctor ring, but if it cannot then the ABS light will go on. It's also possible that one of the reluctor rings has broken or cracked, which would also cause an issue.
[image: Reluctor ring]

I would check the sensors and rings first, before just replacing the ABS module.  Here is another picture that shows where the ring is located relative to the rest of the axle.
[image: A6 drive axle]

Comment: My sensors all appear to be good.  I think I'll send it in to this repair place and see what happend, and if it fixes the problem.